# How to initialize a child class without initializing base class in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, parent-child

So, I have the following parent class;

```
class Parent {
   public Parent() {
      Console.WriteLine ("Parent class")
   }
}
```

And the following child class;

```
class Child : Parent {
   public Child() {
      Console.WriteLine("Child class")
   }
}
```

I know that the constructor of the `Child` class automatically calls `: base()`(or however you call the constructor of the parent from inside the child class). Is there a way to get all of the static functions of the parent without initializing it? (maybe using interfaces?) What would be the way to call the parents constructor from inside the child class (maybe with certain arguments)?

Thanks.

Comment: Static functions are available without creating an instance

Comment: I know, but my question is, how can I derive from a class without automatically initializing it?

Comment: if you could edit the code in the constructor of the parent you could add _it(this is Child)_ { do nothing } else { initialize } but...

Comment: `Child c = new Child{};` then `c.ParentMethod();`?

Comment: Yes, but my code outputs both "Parent class" and "Child class". I want the parent class not to be initialized at all..

Comment: Derived from a class requires you to handle its construction. Please add details to your situation so we can recommend a different approach

Comment: I was asking if there would be a way of deriving from the parent without initializing it, because I did not know how to override a constructor. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: You could write a `protected virtual void Init() { }` method in the base class, which gets called by the base constructor. Override it in the child class and leave it empty.

Comment: Actually, if you don't want to initialize the base class, do inherit from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to write what I think is the simpler and cleaner way:

```
class Parent
{
  public Parent()
  {
    if ( GetType() != typeof(Parent) ) return;
    Console.WriteLine("Parent class");
  }
}

class Child : Parent
{
  public Child()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Child class");
  }
}

static private void Test()
{
  var instance1 = new Parent();
  Console.WriteLine("-");
  var instance2 = new Child();
}
```

*Output*

```html
Parent class
-
Child class
```

I do not recommend doing this kind of thing that is an anti-OOP pattern, and instead rethinking the design of the classes.

But if there is a good reason to do that, you're done.

[How can I prevent a base constructor from being called by an inheritor in C#? (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159296/how-can-i-prevent-a-base-constructor-from-being-called-by-an-inheritor-in-c)

[How can I prevent a base constructor from being called by an inheritor in C#? (iditect.com)](https://www.iditect.com/how-to/53594849.html)

[Ignoring Base Class Constructor (typemock.com)](http://www.typemock.com/docs/?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Fignoringbaseclassconstructor.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are in class scope (not in instance scope). So they cannot be inheritated. Call of parent constructor in child the same as call of default constructor.

```cs
class Parent {
  public Parent(string param) {
  }
}

class Child : Parent {
  public Child() : base("parameter") {
  }
}

class Child2 : Parent {
  public Child(string param1, int param2) : base(param1) {
  }
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to avoid all initializations performed in the base class.

Comment: I understand this. The question is a little misleading.